# Android Annotations generated code location?

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am using android-annotations with dagger2.0 in my project.
Under the build location :

```
build/generated/source/apt/debug/<package>/activity/
```

I see my generated class from dagger like LoadActivity_MembersInjector.java.

**BUT** I am not able to find the classes generated by the android-annotation library itself. I use the `@UiThread` annotation in my activity and would like to see how its gets rewritten by android-annotation lib for running my method on UI thread.
My dependencies :

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

compile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: '2.8'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
apt 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
```

Any pointers on how to access this generated code ?

Comment: The classes are generated to the same place by all processors, like AA. If you cannot find the classes, AA did not run, or there were compilation errors.

Comment: I am using below as my dependencies :  `compile  'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    compile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: '2.8'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    apt 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
` Do they look fine ?

Comment: No, because AndroidAnnotations is not among those dependencies. Please read the [wiki](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle).